Convert MCAP to ROS
I have an MCAP file, which I want to convert to ROS (or other storage formats). I couldn't find any documentation online. Is there any github project available. Any help is appreciated.

Maybe mcap-etl will help:

Presently, mcap_etl supports the following conversions:

From .mcap to .bag
From .mcap to TimescaleDB


Install with
pip install mcap-etl


There is also
rosbag2_storage_mcap (or the current repo rosbag2_storage_mcap)

Use MCAP files with regular ros2 bag commands by adding the --storage mcap option (abbreviated as -s mcap):
$ ros2 bag record -s mcap /topic1 /topic2 ... 
$ ros2 bag play -s mcap path/to/your_recording.mcap
$ ros2 bag info -s mcap path/to/your_recording.mcap


.
